# alternativa para enviar dados obtidos com JS para numa nova página PHP usar os dados

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

Olá!

Meu conhecimento em PHP é básico, mas compreenderei da melhor forma as explicações.

O meu objetivo é criar uma página inicial index.php onde ela obtém a resolução da tela do usuário e esses dados X e Y fiquem guardados em variáveis e assim num formulário. A página chamaria automaticamente uma outra página onde os valores da variável JS sejam utilizadas pelo PHP.

Eu ainda não aprendi Mysql para formular um banco de dados. Já vi várias opções de enviar variáveis até por link, mas nenhum funcionou devidamente.

O pouco que sei de JS é suficiente para obter automaticamente a resulução por meio deste código abaixo:

```
<script>
var x = screen.availWidth;
var y = screen.availHeight;

alert("LARGURA: "+ x +"\nALTURA: " + y)
</script>
```

claro que sem o alert para a página vir a conseguir chamar outra sem intervenção do usuário.

Eu nas minhas pesquisas sei que num único arquivo não dá pra usar as variáveis JS no PHP por que o PHP é executado no servidor e o JS no usuário

Como podem ver eu pensei em usar um formulário que se auto preenchesse com o valor das variáveis do JS. O problema que em JS eu sou mais do que noob. Sendo assim no outro arquivo chamado em seguida o php utilizaria os dados que estão guardados no formulário.

Vi algumas alternativas aqui, mas nenhuma eu consegui de fato utilizar apropriadamente e me surgiu na mente que essa alternativa venha a ser mais rápida.

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: QUando o utilizador chega à pagina queres redirecionar para outra página cujo PHP sabe o tamanho da tela, certo? qual é o url da outra página?

Comment: não decidi exatamente, mas colocaria um link para uma página de logon. A ideia é que essa primeira página não demore mais que alguns segundos e carregue automaticamente para a próxima já com os dados da resolução de tela do usuário. Coloquei a primeira como index.php por já terem me dito que o servidor sempre procura essa pra executar primeiro.

Comment: Se explicares melhor porque precisas de saber o tamanho da tela talvêz possâmos mostrar caminhos para resolver isso.

Comment: Sergio. Como expliquei abaixo é por causa do css. Quando estava modelando a página percebi que quando minimizava a tela do browser tudo saia do lugar. Sendo assim criei uma div que envolvia tudo do site e deu certo. Contudo comecei a pensar que a página poderia se modelar de acordo com o usuário. Vi que dá pra usar variáveis php na página stylesheet, mudando .css para .php e adicionando uns detalhes. Sendo assim se eu tiver os valores logo de cara a página poderá se adaptar automaticamente utilizando variáveis php com os valores obtidos nessa primeira chamada. Compreende.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No JavaScript pode chamar a URL da pagina nova passando os dois valores na Query String da URL.
Ex.

```
http://seudominio.com.br/teste.php?width=" + screen.availWidth + "&height=" + screen.availHeight
```

No php esses valores vão estar disponíveis na variável $_GET["height"] e $_GET["width"].

Agora se esses valores são os únicos que precisa a ferramenta ideal para isso é utilizar Cookies, pois servem exatamente pra isso, gravar valores pequenos que precisem ser enviados para o servidor em cada chamada da pagina.

Um exemplo em php aqui. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775046/setcookie-with-get-method

Agora... se puder melhorar a pergunta irá ficar mais fácil de responder mais especificamente. Que tipo de aplicação é, se roda no servidor ou se roda no cliente, qual objetivo desses valores, etc... Por exemplo, Nas minhas aplicações uso xmlHttpRequest, mas é só para chamar um serviço no Php que retorna um JSON e a partir dai continuo no JavaScript. Sua necessidade pode ser outra.

Comment: a página é basicamente um formulário, a parte principal, contudo ao usar CSS percebi que precisava de uma div que envolvia o site inteiro para que a página não se remodelasse ao novo tamanho tirando tudo do lugar. Sendo assim imaginei que obtendo os valores de resolução de tela eu poderia fazer uma jogada em php e css para com esses valores a página sempre ficasse de acordo com o usuário. 
Vou testar o método que você mostrou e volto depois para comentar!

Comment: Nesse caso, acredito que utilizar CSS puro seria a melhor solução para resolver o seu problema. Se não tiver muita experiencia com CSS (Meu caso) escolha um framework CSS simples e responsivo como por exemplo o Pure CSS. Que assim bastaria criar uma pagina e colocar a classe CSS correta que já estaria dimensionada corretamente para a resolução do usuário. Internamente isso é feito com o recurso Media Queries do CSS.

Comment: vou procurar acerca desse Media Queries do CSS. Já estou vendo uma página aqui e estou achando realmente interessante. Grato!

Comment: compreendi o uso das Media Queries. Em suma eu vou fazer uma stylesheet onde dentro dela colocarei para cada tipo de resolução uma solução. De fato uma opção limpa e simples. Uma dúvida somente. Há alguma exceção pra esse tipo de chamada do CSS?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, como disse não sou especialista em CSS. Tenho utilizado frameworks para responsividade. Não esqueça de dar up vote em respostas que tenha julgado úteis, e se conseguir resolver o problema aceitar uma das respostas como correta.

Comment: Vou justificar por que escolhi esta resposta, apesar de não ter utilizado o método de links esta me permitiu conhecer um modo mais interessante para resolver a questão. Grato @Vitor!

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT
jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    $.post('alerta.php', { width: screen.width, height:screen.height }, function(json) {
        if(json.outcome == 'success') {
            // do something with the knowledge possibly?
        } else {
            alert('Impossível deixar o PHP saber a resolução da tela!');
        }
    },'json');
});
```

**PHP (alerta.php)**

```
<?php
// Você pode fazer algo parecido com isto:
if(isset($_POST['width']) && isset($_POST['height'])) {
    $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_POST['width'];
    $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_POST['height'];
    echo json_encode(array('outcome'=>'success'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('outcome'=>'error','error'=>"Não é possível definir a resolução."));
}
?>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Blz

Comment: Não faça referência a sites que nada têm haver com a resposta. Isso é considerado ***Spam***

Comment: Vou testar e retorno depois para comentar! De todo modo já agradeço! =]